# Operation on Complex conjugate

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, wavefunction, hilbert-space, conventions

Why do we sandwich operators in quantum mechanics in such a way that the operator acts on the wavefunction and not on its complex conjugate?

Comment: In part it's conventional.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\int\psi^* \hat{F} \varphi  = \int (\hat{F}^+ \psi)^* \varphi 
$$

also, if F is an Hermitian operator 
$$
\int \Psi \hat{F} \Psi^*  = \int \Psi^* \hat{F}\Psi 
$$

Answer (score 0):

Take the kinetic energy operator and ground state wave function for a particle in a box with width of $L$ as an example (in 1D)
$$\hat{T}=-\frac{\hbar}{2m}\frac{d}{dx^2}$$
and
$$\psi=\sqrt{\frac{2}{L}}\sin\frac{\pi}{L}x$$
Obviously, $\hat{T}\psi$ means something and $\psi^{*}\hat{T}$ means something else.

Please look at [my previous answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/289108/bra-ket-notation/289195#289195) for a more complete explanation of the notation.

Comment: "...becomes an object for which no computation can be performed." What do you mean? Surely, you can multiply a matrix 1x2 times 2x2 matrix.

Comment: thx for pointing out my mistake, I have removed that part completely