# On Dirac notation: inner product vs base representation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, notation, quantum-states

The Dirac notation $\langle a | b \rangle$ seems somewhat ambiguous.

1. On one hand, it can be seen as inner product of elements $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ of the Hilbert space $\scr H$, namely: $$\langle a | b \rangle ={\displaystyle}\int_\mathbb R a^*(x) \ b(x) \ dx.\tag{1}$$
2. On the other hand, it's the evaluation of $b$ at its $a$th component, with respect to a particular orthonormal base for $\scr H$.

   - *discrete case*. $$\langle n | b\rangle = b_n, \tag{2d}$$
     where $\displaystyle \sum_n |n\rangle\langle n | = \mathbb I\ $ and $\langle n | m \rangle = \delta_{nm}.$
   - *continuous case*.
     $$\langle x | b\rangle = b(x), \tag{2c}$$
     where $\displaystyle \int_\mathbb R |x\rangle\langle x | = \mathbb I\ $ and $\langle x | x' \rangle = \delta(x- x').$

The obvious conclusion is that you are free to see $\langle a | b \rangle$ in both ways, that is, 1. and 2. are equivalent.

But it can't be! For instance:

$$b(x) \stackrel{(2c)}{=} \langle x | b\rangle \stackrel{(1)}{\neq} \displaystyle \int _\mathbb R x b(x) dx.\tag{3}$$

So? How can I choose the right way to see it *a priori*?

Comment: Note that $|x\rangle$ is not an element of $\mathscr{H}$; in particular, the position states do not form a complete orthonormal basis (e.g. $\langle x|x\rangle$ is not well-defined).

Comment: Additionally, the inner product you've given is only applicable for $\mathscr{H}=L^2(\mathbb{R})$ functions, no?

Comment: Your assertions 1 and 2 are indeed equivalent. You will get more useful answers if you explain in more detail why you think they are incompatible. What do you mean by "$b(x) \neq \displaystyle \int _\mathbb R x b(x) dx$", and why do you think those two should be equal?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I think OP is saying that $\langle x|b\rangle = \displaystyle \int _\mathbb R\mathrm{d}x\, x\, b(x)$ from the perspective of a scalar product.

Comment: Your (3) is nonsense: Dirac takes special care in his book to remind you the wave function of $|x\rangle$ is a delta function, not x.

Comment: Related, probably useful: [Bra-Ket Notation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/289108/bra-ket-notation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given
$$
\mathbb{I} = \int |x\rangle\langle x| \,\mathrm{d}x
$$
You can rewrite the scalarproduct $\langle x | b\rangle = b(x)$ by inserting a 'one' in the middle
\begin{align*}
\langle x | b \rangle &= \langle x | \mathbb{I} | b\rangle = \int \langle x | x'\rangle \langle x'| b\rangle \,\mathrm{d}x' \\
&= \int \delta(x-x')b(x') \,\mathrm{d}x' \\
&= b(x) 
\end{align*}

This explains how to get the right result, but I'm honestly not sure where you made a mistake.

Comment: I think the mistake in OP's equation (3) is simply that it is not an inner product between two $L^2$ functions; so equation (1) is not applicable.

Comment: @Jakob his mistake is using the wrong wave function!

Comment: Yes, these are two ways of seeing the same problem I guess. Anyway, thank you all